# Authorizing users so they can only view their own objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization

I have a user model and users have many patients. A user should only be able to view their own patients.

What's the best way to implement this?

Here is my original patients show action. This allows any logged in user to view any patient:

```
 def show
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    @assessments = @patient.assessments
  end
```

I can switch it to below, but then I get an error page (patient id not found) and I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle it:

```
 def show
    @patient = current_user.patients.find(params[:id])
    @assessments = @patient.assessments
  end
```

What's the best approach for handling simple authorizations like this? Nothing fancy, just want users to only be able to view and edit their own stuff.

---

**Edit**

Here is the error I get when trying to access another user's patient:

```
Couldn't find Patient with 'id'=27 [WHERE "patients"."user_id" = ?]
```

Instead, I'd prefer to show the user a flash message saying they're not authorized.

Comment: You are on the right way, can you show your show action params

Comment: This should work. Can you show error message?

Comment: what are you trying to pass through the params? the patient id?? I think you should use `exists?`, because if such a patient id is passed which does not belong to the current user, it would return patient id nil..

Comment: I guess the association is not done properly, can you show us the association.

Comment: User has_many :patients and has_many :assessments. Patient belongs_to :user and has_many :assessments. Assessment belongs_to :user and belongs_to :assessment.  If users try to access a restricted patient, I want to show them a custom flash message instead of the rails error page "Couldn't find Patient with 'id'=27 [WHERE "patients"."user_id" = ?]"

Comment: I think maybe it's working. Originally I was trying to avoid showing rails error page to user if they type in wrong parameter into URL. But I'm not sure if this can be done

Answer (score 0):

def show

```
 @patient = Patient.where(id: params[:id],user_id: current_user.id)
 @assessments = @patient.assessments
```

end

here @pateint will give all the patient of the current login users & @assessments will give asssessments related to patients.

Comment: That would require modification because the `where` clause returns a relation, not a record. The relation could be empty, or contain one record.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [find_by](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by), which does not throw an error if nothing is found.

```
def show
  @patient = Patient.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if @patient && @patient.user == current_user
    @assessments = @patient.assessments
  elsif @patient.user != current_user
    flash.now[:danger] = 'You are not authorized!'
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'The patient was not found'
  end
end
```

Then you should test in your view if the patient exists.

That looks a little messy and repetitive, however, so you could refactor, for example by making a new function. Put this in the model `patient.rb`, and if `current_user` comes from `application_helper`, you may have to `include ApplicationHelper`.

```
authorized?
  self.id == current_user.id
end
```

Now the conditional of the first code example could be like this:

```
if @patient
  @assessments = @patient.assessments 
  unless @patient.authorized?
    flash[:danger] = 'You are not authorized!'
    # here, redirect the user away from the show page
  end
else
  flash.now[:danger] = 'The patient was not found'
end
```